# Struts 2 JSON JQuery Grid does not hit Action

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, jqgrid

I currently have a table which I am trying to convert into jqGrid. I cannot get the request to hit the controller's action that gets me the JSON result.

**Here's my relevant Maven configuration:**

```xml
<!-- Struts2 Libraries -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Here's my `struts.xml` configuration:**

```xml
<package name="opd" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
        
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <!-- Result Types -->
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"   class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />          
    </result-types>

    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <!-- Interceptors -->
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="appInterceptor" class="com.OrthoPatientDirect.OPDWeb.interceptor.ApplicationInterceptor" />
....
        <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>          
    </interceptors>
....
<package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="opd">
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <!-- Admin Manage Patient                           -->
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    
    <action name="patients_*" class="com.OrthoPatientDirect.OPDWeb.action.ManagePatientAction" method="{1}">
    
            <result name="listHome"   type="tiles">admin.managePatientList</result>
            <result name="listByProcedure"  type="tiles">admin.managePatientList.Procedure</result>             
            <result name="update" type="tiles">admin.managePatientList</result> 
            <result name="deletePatient" type="tiles">admin.managePatientList</result>  
            <result name="getJsonData" type="json" />   
            <interceptor-ref name="appInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" /> 
        <interceptor-ref name="json"  />                                                                        
    </action>   

....
```

Here's my controller and action. I left out other jQuery specific properties. I am not using annotation. There are other actions that get called from the tabs that populate data.

```java
public String getJSON()
{
    return getJsonData();
}


public String getJsonData()
{
    //Count Rows 
    records = getPatientList().size();
       
    //calculate the total pages for the query
    total = records;
    
    return "getJsonData";
    
}
```

**This is my view related to jqGrid:**

```jsp
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>

<sj:head jqueryui="true"/>

<s:url var="remoteurl" action="patients_getJsonData"/>

<sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        caption="View Patients"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="patientList"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
>
       
    <sjg:gridColumn name="email" index="email" title="Email" sortable="true"/>
       
</sjg:grid>
```

I am open to any suggestion. There is no bad answer. I know there are other questions in SO related to this, but I only found ones that use annotation or ones that don't have any answers. This may/may not be a version issue. I tried the other day to upgrade but ran into conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: 1) Please use always same version for jquery and jquery grid plugin. Current version is 3.7.0.
2) Is your JSON action invoked or are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Wow what a *neat mess* :) wildcard methods starting with get returning theirselves as result O_o BTW you should upgrade ALSO due to very important security issues. You should use 2.3.16 everywhere for Struts (core, json, etc) and 3.7.0 for Jquery AND grid.

Comment: BUT you cannot use 3.7.0 with 2.2.1 and latest S2 is 2.3.16.1. :)

Comment: I will try to upgrade. Ran into issues. Is there a way to see what Struts Jquery Grid documentation looked like at older versions?

Comment: I was using 3.0.3Release version of spring. What version are you all using? Hopefully I don't have to upgrade to version 4. That would not be good solution to just get jquery grid working.

Answer (score 0):

Many `sjg` related errors are due to the incorrectly mapping the action used to return a JSON result available to the Struts2 jQuery Grid exposed by the plugin. So, to fix the error you should correctly map the url to the action.  For example

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" namespace="/admin" action="patients_getJsonData"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="View Patients"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{#remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="patientList"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true">
    <sjg:gridColumn name="email" index="email" title="Email" sortable="true"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

get the variable from the context, don't traverse the value stack.

To get JSON result from the URL referenced in the grid you don't need to use wildcards. Create the separate action configuration to get json data. For this action only params interceptor makes sense, other interceptors are vague. The action class should contain all necessary fields with getters/setters and properly initialized. See examples of the grid from the struts2 [jQuery Grid Showcase](https://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase).

Comment: I will try this. I will let you know if this works. It does look like the namespace will fix it.

Comment: Added that namespace. Also tried without the forward slash. Did not work. I will try upgrading the library as others have suggested.

Comment: @TejaswiRana I know you have a complex of bugs that I can't fix in one answer, but the question wa could you hit the action with the url?

Comment: Can't. I can't get it to hit the action.

Comment: I just tried to upgrade the library version. There are too many other dependencies and one change leads to another. I am not going that road as suggested by other users. I somehow need to use the same lib version and get it to hit the action. I wish I could find the documentation on the older version of struts 2 jquery grid.

Comment: I remember the issue was with underline in wildcards, you could find it in my answers. Try to remove it and use for readability camel cased names. Also json interceptor if you are using it should order first in the stack.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain why json interceptor has to be first in the stack. I vaguely remember this from three years ago. The wildcards should not be an issue. Although for readability it makes sense. I am +1 ing you for your credible answers. Hopefully, if your answers get it done, I will accept it to. Otherwise nobody will look at it if it looks like it is answered.